# Apache Spark K-Means clustering - RDD for input

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark

I'm trying to run Spark's k-means clustering over grouped data but I'm getting a variety of errors when I try to cluster each group.

The input RDD looks like (userID: Long, coords: [Vector]) i.e.:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Seq[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector])]
```

The Vector contains X Y coordinates i.e. pairs of Doubles.  I want to identify coordinate clusters for each UserID, so I'm mapping over the RDD, and trying to run k-means for each group:

```
val userClusters = userCoordVectors.map {
  case (userId, coords) =>
    val clusters = 4
    val iterations = 30
    // Need to convert coords to RDD for input into K-Means
    val parsedData = sc.parallelize(coords)

    // Apply k-means
    val model = KMeans.train(parsedData, clusters, iterations)
    ...
    etc
}
```

But when I run this, I get a NPE from the line:

```
val parsedData = sc.parallelize(coords)
```

The problem is, I have to convert the coords to an RDD for the K-Means operation.

On the other hand, if I collect the input RDD first, then I don't get the NPE.  Instead, I get a Java heap error, presumably because I'm materialising the whole RDD.

```
 val userClusters = sc.parallelize(userCoordVectors.collect.map {
 ...
 })
```

Collecting the data in this RDD just seems wrong here, so I'm assuming there ought to be a better way, but I don't know how else to get the parsedData line to work.

Can anybody see any obvious mistakes in how I'm trying to use the K-Means stuff here, or suggest how to achieve the goal of clustering my data within each group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use SparkContext or RDD inside any function of RDD operators. They cannot be serialized and sent via network.

Matei Zaharia answered here: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Can-we-get-a-spark-context-inside-a-mapper-td9605.html

> You currently can't use SparkContext inside a Spark task, so in this case you'd have to call some kind of local K-means library. One example you can try to use is Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). You can then load your text files as an RDD of strings with SparkContext.wholeTextFiles and call Weka on each one.

Comment: OK, that sounds pretty conclusive.  Thanks for the tip re. Weka.  I might also try PySpark and one of the Python ML libraries instead.